# Как из данных из файла сделать массив смежности

Tags: java, алгоритм

Считываю данные с файла в  виде:

```
AB3
AC6
CB1
DE4
CD32
```

Код :

```
 public void readData(String filePath) {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            int a = 0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                roads.add(line.split("\\s"));
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Как сделать из него массив смежности, типа:
[image: Где синие цифры как буквы]

Comment: Если б вы еще написали, что такое XY99 - цены б вопросу не было :) А если это ребро из X в Y с весом 99 - то судя по вашей картинке, нужно просто игнорировать вес ребра...

Comment: да это то что вы говорите, но мне нужно сделать так чтобы вместо единиц как раз был вес ребра

Comment: Ну так разобрать на две буквы и число? в чем проблема?

Comment: Можете показать пример? Как это реализовать?

Comment: На С/С++ - пожалуйста. Но Java - это ваш инструмент. Мне чужим молотком - не с руки. Но если у вас проблема именно в этом - то вы задаете неверный вопрос! У вас не проблема "как из данных из файла сделать массив смежности", у вас проблема "как разделить слово на части"...

Comment: Минимальный поиск сообщает, что первый символ вы получаете как `line.charAt(0)`, второй - `line.charAt(1)`, вес - как `Integer.parseInt(line.substring(2))`. Если это за 3 минуты нашел я, который в Java ни бельмеса - то в чем у вас **реальная** проблема?... Может, она не в программировании? :)

Comment: @Harry зачем же вы чужой хлеб отбираете? Или поумничать больше негде?

Comment: `.split("\\s")` разделает строку по одному пробелу. А вам это не надо. Ответы выше от сишника

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець И чем я "отбил чужой хлеб", прокомментировав вопрос? Кто вам мешает дать нормальный *ответ*? Опять же, дорога ложка к обеду :) - между моим и вашим комментарием прошло более 9 часов. Вот и судите сами, что для вас важнее - собственный интерес или помощь человеку? :) P.S. Если я дал неверный ответ - то почему вы с ним согласились? А если верный - то при чем тут "умничать"?...